# Equal Spacing from one another for Buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, spacing

I was wondering if anyone could help me...

I am trying to have perfect spacing between buttons for a soundboard app, but I cant seem to get it quite right even after using constraints etc.

I have attached an image to show you what I mean...

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Image looking good distance between buttons is uniform. only distance to edges is different

Comment: All I have done so far is to space them as best I can by eye and then add the appropriate constraints such as, 'equal widths' and 'equal heights'. I will look into the UICollectionView as well as experimenting further...

Comment: also for this approach see equally spaced views

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Like This

i took 3 UIView on storyboard and give equal width of UIView than i put button on view and give button x centre by back view please see the attached screen shot of storyboard
[image]

Comment: this looks really good! How did you gain equal spacing between the vertical columns of buttons?

Comment: i give equal width & leading ,treling spece =0 between UIview so view mange it self as per width of Device,  and button set by UIView's horizontal centre  so any how button stick at center of UIView  that's it